# Testng stopped working with gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, testng, build.gradle

My framework stopped working suddenly. I have integrated gradle with Testng and use to run my scripts through testng.xml in gradle

No its always failing on compfile time check in gradle. If run normal from IntelliJ it run fine.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

plugins {
    id 'java'
}
/*apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "com.xxxxxxx.smsApi.qa.framework.mainRunner"*/

group 'api_automation'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
/*
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
*/

/*// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://mvnrepository.com/maven2'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://download.java.net/maven/2'
    }
}

war {
    baseName = 'api_automation'
}*/
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("test-output/reports/")
    }
    useTestNG()
            {
                useDefaultListeners = true
                options.suites("src/test/java/testApi_Test_Scripts/smsApiAutomationSuite.xml")
                options.listeners << 'com.kaleyra.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.CustomListener'
                //options.listeners << 'com.kaleyra.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.EmailListener'
                //options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
                options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
                systemProperty 'org.uncommons.reportng.title', 'sms_api_automation_results'

            }
    testLogging.events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = "full"

/*    //Disable the default groovy html reports since ReportNG is being used
    reports.html.enabled = false
    reports.junitXml.enabled=true
    reports.junitXml.destination=file("output/")*/

    //Interceptors
    beforeTest { desc ->
        println "\n*** Starting execution of test ${desc.className}.${desc.name} ***"
    }
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        println "<<< Test ${descriptor.name} resulted in ${result.resultType} and took "+getElaspedTime(result.endTime - result.startTime)+" >>>\n"
    }

    //Modify the test logging
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
    test {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
}
dependencies {

    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    //An assertion library that is better than JUnit defaults
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    //Better reporting for testng.  It outputs a nice html report
    testCompile 'org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor', name: 'htmlcompressor', version: '1.5.2'
    compile group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: "com.github.fge", name: "json-schema-validator", version: "2.2.6"
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.guice-repository', name: 'guice-repository', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.easytesting', name: 'fest-assert-core', version: '2.0M10'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile 'com.relevantcodes:extentreports:2.41.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'

}
def getElaspedTime(def time) {

    if(time / 1000 < 1)
    {
        return String.format("0 min, %.3f sec", time/1000)
    }
    else
    {
        return String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(time) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time))

        )
    }
}
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

Not sure what to do. My 90% project work depended on this automation.

Till last weekend it was fine. Not sure why it just stopped suddenly where as I have made no changes to it.

When I run gradle build

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\xxxxx\src\main\java\framework\collection\Groups.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
import org.testng.Assert;

        Assert.assertEquals(responseSample.getStatusCode(),200);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Assert
  location: class XMLSendSMS
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:21: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        Reporter.log("<b>Executing TestCase - " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()+" --> "+result.getMethod().getDescription()+"</b><br>\n");
        ^
  symbol:   variable Reporter
  location: class CustomListener
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:33: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:54: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\sobhit.s\Documents\gradle-example\src\main\java\framework\listener\CustomListener.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
            if (!(result.getThrowable() instanceof SkipException)) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class SkipException
  location: class CustomListener
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors
```

I have added testng but still fails. No idea why suddenly it started. If I run directly works fine. but does'nt work with gradle build. It was working before with gradle build as well but from last 3 days its happening.

As yole said in below comment- i have removed testCompile and given as compile for which now compilation error is not there but this what i got-

```
16:21:35 > Task :compileJava
16:21:35 Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
16:21:35 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16:21:47 
16:21:47 > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
16:21:47 > Task :classes
16:21:47 > Task :jar
16:21:47 > Task :assemble
16:21:48 > Task :compileTestJava FAILED
16:21:48 
16:21:48 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:21:48 
16:21:48 * What went wrong:
16:21:48 Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
16:21:48 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
16:21:48    > Could not find testng-jdk15.jar (org.testng:testng:6.9.10).
16:21:48      Searched in the following locations:
16:21:48          https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.9.10/testng-6.9.10-jdk15.jar
```

Comment: What do you mean by "failing on compile time check"? Please specify the exact command that you run, and if it produces an error message, please post it.

Comment: @yole I have updated the error logs as well. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `testCompile` dependency on testng, so it's only available in test sources (src/test). However, you have some code in production sources (src/main) referencing testng, and it doesn't compile because the dependency isn't visible there. You need to change `testCompile` to a regular `compile` dependency.

Comment: as you said removed the testCompile and instead of that given as compile and compilation error didnot come as above but this is new error updating in my post